I am confused about the formula SST = SSE + SSR
I dont know why in this case this formula does not hold.. Can someone explain?

it's not true just for any vector of numbers; the predictions have to come from a linear regression, or more precisely, the predictions have to be orthogonal to the residuals.

Welcome to Cross Validated! I believe my linked question and self-answer address this issue. If they do not, please say what confusion remains. Briefly, that decomposition is the exception, not the rule, as Madden mentions above.
